# What does "sequential memory-hard" mean?

Tags: scrypt, argon2, memory-hard

I found this term in Scrypt's paper.  I have several questions about its meaning, ranging from how to parse it, to theoretical bounds:

#### **Q1:** How to parse it?

- Is it read `(sequential memory)-hard`?
- Or `sequential (memory-hard)`?

#### **Q2:** What does it mean?

- Does it mean that as space is *linearly* reduced, then penalty is that is *exponentially* increased?
- Can we tell what is that exponent?  Or does suffice to simply be an exponent, regardless of which exponent?
- In current practice, can we say something more specific about what that exponent for state-of-art functions beyond just *"it's exponential"*?  I think it is within reach to make more specific claims.
- Ideally, is there any theorem that shows an upper bound for this exponent?  E.g. can we say, for every reduced *single* unit of memory, amount of computation performed *doubles*?  *Tripples*? *Quadruples*? ...?

#### **Q3:** Any better name?

- Is the name used in Scrypt's paper still the most accurate name?
- Is there a better name for it that the cool kids like to use nowadays more?  In Argon2's paper, as well as [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-hard_function), it seems to be called `memory-hard`.  Does it mean that `memory-hard` is the better name to adopt?  E.g. what do the coolest gurus in top cryptographic journals tend to use?
- Optional: any reason the Scrypt paper didn't call it `memory-hard`?  Or was it just the randomness of life?

---

#### Appendix

I did look at previous related answers, and I found these:

- [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/84002/memory-hard-vs-memory-bound-functions) only asks about such functions in relation to another function.  Thus doesn't dig deep into what such functions are in themselves.
- [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27363/memory-hard-password-based-key-derivation-functions) only asks about the motivations of such functions.
- [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30918/big-block-cipher-as-memory-hard-function) asks whether his function is a good one among such functions.

Answer (score 4):

The Scrypt paper [here](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf) defines memory-hard and sequential memory hard, and accordingly explains why one was used over the other.

> **Definition 1**. A memory-hard algorithm on a Random Access Machine is an algorithm which uses $S(n)$ space and $T(n)$ operations, where $S(n) \in \Omega (T(n)^{1-\epsilon})$

> **Definition 2**. A sequential memory-hard function is a function which 
>  (a) can be computed by a memory-hard algorithm on a Random Access Machine
> in $T(n)$ operations; and 
>  (b) cannot be computed on a Parallel Random Access Machine with $S∗(n)$ processors and $S
> ∗(n)$ space in expected time $T∗(n)$ where $S∗(n)T∗(n) =\mathcal{O}(T(n)^{2-x})$ for any $x > 0$.

> Put another way, a sequential memory-hard function is one where not only the
> fastest *sequential* algorithm is memory-hard, but additionally where it is impossible
> for a *parallel* algorithm to asymptotically achieve a significantly lower cost. Since
> memory-hard algorithms asymptotically come close to using the most space possible given their running time, and memory is the computationally usable resource
> general-purpose computers have which is most expensive to reproduce in hardware
> , we believe that, for any given running time on a sequential general-purpose computer, functions which are sequential memory-hard come close to being the most
> expensive possible functions to compute in hardware.

Comment: What does $1- \epsilon$ do?  Couldn't find it in paper.

Comment: Is Argon2 not sequential memory hard?  But just memory hard?  Any reason Argon2 didn't do it like Scrypt?

Comment: Good question, I've asked it [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87361/is-argon2-sequential-memory-hard).

Comment: Just to help others understand what I'm lacking:  I read those quotes from the Scrypt paper, but I'm not sure if I understood them correctly, and historically I tent to misunderstand things, so I'm too wary to trust my thoughts.  Hence I'd really appreciate if someone could specifically answer my sub-questions under my questions. Specifically, the 4 questions under **Q2**.  _(side note: thanks a lot for posting that question.  It helps me a lot.)_

Comment: @caveman I'll probably ask a follow-up to that as it appears difficult to answer.  I've edited the answer to include the fuller explanation.  I think your Q2 is answered as it's sub-questions rely on a meaning not defined in the paper.  It might be better to ask another question that gets to the crux of your question, and is self-contained.