# Is Argon2 "sequential memory hard"?

Tags: scrypt, argon2, memory-hard

The Scrypt paper [here](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf) defines memory-hard and sequential memory hard functions as follows:

> **Definition 1**. A memory-hard algorithm on a Random Access Machine is an algorithm which uses $S(n)$ space and $T(n)$ operations, where $S(n) \in \Omega (T(n)^{1-\epsilon})$

> **Definition 2**. A sequential memory-hard function is a function which 
>  (a) can be computed by a memory-hard algorithm on a Random Access Machine
> in $T(n)$ operations; and 
>  (b) cannot be computed on a Parallel Random Access Machine with $S∗(n)$ processors and $S
> ∗(n)$ space in expected time $T∗(n)$ where $S∗(n)T∗(n) =\mathcal{O}(T(n)^{2-x})$ for any $x > 0$.

> Put another way, a sequential memory-hard function is one where not only the
> fastest sequential algorithm is memory-hard, but additionally where it is impossible
> for a parallel algorithm to asymptotically achieve a significantly lower cost. Since
> memory-hard algorithms asymptotically come close to using the most space possible given their running time, and memory is the computationally usable resource
> general-purpose computers have which is most expensive to reproduce in hardware8
> ,
> we believe that, for any given running time on a sequential general-purpose computer, functions which are sequential memory-hard come close to being the most
> expensive possible functions to compute in hardware.

However the specification for [Argon2](https://www.cryptolux.org/images/0/0d/Argon2.pdf) refers only to 'memory hard' functions.

> In the case of the password hashing, we suppose that the defender allocates certain amount of time (e.g., 1
> second) per password and a certain number of CPU cores (e.g., 4 cores). Then he hashes the password using the
> maximum amount M of memory. This memory size translates to certain ASIC area A. The running ASIC time $T$ is determined by the length of the longest computational chain and by the ASIC memory latency. Therefore,
> we maximize the value $AT$. The other use cases follow a similar procedure.
> Suppose that an ASIC designer that wants to reduce the memory and thus the area wants to compute $H$
> using $αM$ memory only for some $α < 1$. Using some tradeoff specific to $H$, he has to spend $C(α)$ times as much
> computation and his running time increases by at least the factor $D(α)$. Therefore, the maximum possible gain
> $E$ in the time-area product is:

> $E_{max} = max α  \frac{1}{(αD(α)}$
> .

> The hash function is called memory-hard if $D(α) > 1/α$ as $α → 0$.

**Questions**

1. Is Argon2 sequential memory hard per the specification set out in the Scrypt paper?
2. If not, why? Is it a case of different definitions or a completely different approach?

Comment: Mybe I'm missing something, but, to me, it seems that Argon2 is very similar to $\text{ROMix}_H$ that's introduced in Scrypt's paper in page 6, which is later claimed to be _sequential memory-hard_ by **Theorem 1** in page 8.  I didn't check the proofs in detail, but I _feel_ Argon2 is of the same class of functions that falls under **Theorem 1**. Yet, Argon2's paper only calls itself _"memory-hard"_.  Something is inconsistent here (hopefully it is my understanding, so that I learn something new!).